# Orientation of $X \times Y$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Suppose that $X$ is not orientable. How can I show that $X \times Y$ is never orientable, no matter what manifold $Y$ may be?

I've tried supposing that $X \times Y$ is orientable, then using that $\pi\colon X\times Y\to X$ the projection on first coordinate is orientation preserving map, $X$ would be orientable. But something just not sounds right.

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$? Topological manifolds? Smooth manifolds? Depending on this, proofs will be more or less difficult.

Comment: Also, what definition(s) of orientability are you working with? Your idea can be made to work by noticing that the tangent bundle of $X \times Y$ is $TX \times TY$.

Comment: I'm working with Guillemin-Pollack definition of orientation. X and Y are connected manifolds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof in the smooth setting. One of the (many) equivalent definitions of orientability is the following: Let $M$ be a smooth connected manifold, $p:\tilde M\to M$ is its universal cover and $G$ the group of covering transformations. Note that $\tilde M$ is always orientable. Then $M$ is orientable if and only if $G$ preserves orientation on $\tilde M$.

Suppose now that $M$ is not orientable and let $g\in G$ be an orientation-reversing element, i.e., with respect to the orientation atlas on $\tilde M$, the Jacobian determinant $J_g$ is negative. Now, consider another connected smooth manifold $N$ and its universal cover $\tilde N$ and the group of covering transformations $H$. Then the universal cover of $M\times N$ is 
$\tilde M \times \tilde N$ and the group of covering transformations is $G\times H$ where every element of $G$ acts on $\tilde N$ via the identity map. Computing the Jacobian determinant of 
$$
(g,Id): \tilde M \times \tilde N\to \tilde M \times \tilde N$$
we obtain that it equals $J_g$, i.e., is negative. Thus, $M\times N$ is non-orientable.

You can now finish the proof in case $M$ or $N$ is not connected.

The same conclusion holds for topological manifolds, but the proof is a bit more involved (you need to know Kunneth formula and homological interpretation of orientability).

Comment: Thanks!!!

I'll try to understand the definition using groups of transformation. The definition I use is "an orientation of X, manifold with boundary" is a smooth choice of orientations for all tangent spaces $T_x X$." (as in G&P pp 96)

X and Y are connected.